# How to resolve promises from nested firebase queries?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to get specific documents that are referenced in a different collection. The code that I have got so far is this, but the promise in the useEffect doesn't resolve in time.

The structure is as follows:

```
conversations -> id -> {users : [users_id, user_id]}
```

The aim is to get the users profile for each specific conversation

What exactly am I doing wrong in the promises array?

Or maybe there is a better way to get referenced ids from a different collection?

```
const conversationsRef = firestore.collection("conversations").where("users", "array-contains", auth.currentUser.uid).orderBy("updatedAt", "desc");


const [convo, set] = useState([]);
async function getConversations(){
    let test = []
    await conversationsRef.onSnapshot((snap) => {
         snap.forEach((doc) => {
            let conversation = doc.data();
            conversation.users.forEach((user) => {
                if(user != auth.currentUser.uid){
                    firestore.collection("users").doc(user).get().then((user_profile) =>{
                        conversation.po = user_profile.data();
                        test.push(conversation);
                    });
                }
            });
        })
    });
    return Promise.all(test);
}

useEffect(()=>{
    getConversations().then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
        console.log(data[0]?.hostId);
        setActiveChat(data[0]);
        set(data);
    })
},[])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're actually resolving the `firestore.collection('users')` promise inside a `forEach` loop which is not async. You aren't pushing a valid promise to the `Promise.all`. Rather than pushing `conversation`, you need to push the actual function that returns a promise, `firestore.collection("users").doc(user).get()`. Try this:

```js
async function getConversations(){
    const promises = []
    await conversationsRef.onSnapshot((snap) => {
         snap.forEach((doc) => {
            let conversation = doc.data();
            conversation.users.forEach((user) => {
                if(user != auth.currentUser.uid){
                 promises.push(firestore.collection("users").doc(user).get())
                }
            });
        })
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! 
If I understood your code correctly then this would only resolve the users object and not the whole conversations object with the user object added to the conversation.

To get what I want - would I then have to push promises.push(conversation) after the forEach? But then how would I resolve the users obj promise?